# Printing PDF shows binary numbers in the left side

Tags: 18.04, wine, printing, libreoffice, pdf

so I am having this problem since morning about printing a document in Ubuntu. (Ubuntu 18.04)

This is my first time printing a document in Ubuntu. I have tried using Okular, LibreOffice, Microsoft Word (wine). When I try to print, it is actually printing something but just random numbers and symbols.

I also tried printing it online but still the same. There is no problem with the printer actually because all of my workmates are able to print their documents (windows 10) except mine which happens to be Ubuntu.

Please help.

Printer: EPSON L405 Series

[view image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2NFa.jpg)

Comment: What printer do you have and have you installed it correctly in Ubuntu. Please edit your question with further details.

Comment: already edited sir

Comment: any help here? https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-an-Epson-Printer-L405-on-Ubuntu-16-04-LTS

Comment: didn't help me either

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions? I badly needed to print something here asap

Comment: Save the print file as a pdf and email it to a colleague who can access the printer (as an immediate solution) ?

Answer (score 0):

I have an Epson L4150, but I was facing the same problem.

I connected the printer and the Ubuntu installed the drivers automatically. Didn't work. Installed the drivers manually. Didn't worked.

Then, I deleted the printer, and added one manually:

1. Access printer configs.
2. Delete the existing one.
3. Click on *Add*, or *Add new*.
4. Select the same Epson option.

Other option is to add the printer using CUPS. For doing that, access `localhost:631` using Mozilla (Chrome didn't work for me). Then, click *Administration menu → Printers → Add printer*.